# Apt installed postgres version does not match pg_config version

Tags: 14.04, apt, postgresql

Using a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04, we've added the necessary apt repo, updated apt, and then installed Postgres-9.5. However, trying to install psycopg2@2.6.1 we get an error...

```
Error: could not determine PostgreSQL version from '10.0'
```

Which seems a little odd, so I give the following a go...

```
psql -c "select version()"
```

Which returns...

```
PostgreSQL 9.5.9 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4, 64-bit
```

And just to double check, I try...

```
pg_config
```

Which gives the following...

```
BINDIR = /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin
DOCDIR = /usr/share/doc/postgresql-doc-10
HTMLDIR = /usr/share/doc/postgresql-doc-10
INCLUDEDIR = /usr/include/postgresql
PKGINCLUDEDIR = /usr/include/postgresql
INCLUDEDIR-SERVER = /usr/include/postgresql/10/server
LIBDIR = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
PKGLIBDIR = /usr/lib/postgresql/10/lib
LOCALEDIR = /usr/share/locale
MANDIR = /usr/share/postgresql/10/man
SHAREDIR = /usr/share/postgresql/10
SYSCONFDIR = /etc/postgresql-common
PGXS = /usr/lib/postgresql/10/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk
CONFIGURE = '--with-icu' '--with-tcl' '--with-perl' '--with-python' '--with-pam' '--with-openssl' '--with-libxml' '--with-libxslt' '--with-tclconfig=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tcl8.6' '--with-includes=/usr/include/tcl8.6' 'PYTHON=/usr/bin/python' '--mandir=/usr/share/postgresql/10/man' '--docdir=/usr/share/doc/postgresql-doc-10' '--sysconfdir=/etc/postgresql-common' '--datarootdir=/usr/share/' '--datadir=/usr/share/postgresql/10' '--bindir=/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin' '--libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/' '--libexecdir=/usr/lib/postgresql/' '--includedir=/usr/include/postgresql/' '--enable-nls' '--enable-integer-datetimes' '--enable-thread-safety' '--enable-tap-tests' '--enable-debug' '--disable-rpath' '--with-uuid=e2fs' '--with-gnu-ld' '--with-pgport=5432' '--with-system-tzdata=/usr/share/zoneinfo' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -pie -fno-omit-frame-pointer' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' '--with-gssapi' '--with-ldap' '--with-includes=/usr/include/mit-krb5' '--with-libs=/usr/lib/mit-krb5' '--with-libs=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mit-krb5' '--with-selinux' 'CPPFLAGS=-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2'
CC = gcc
CPPFLAGS = -DFRONTEND -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/mit-krb5
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -g -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -pie -fno-omit-frame-pointer
CFLAGS_SL = -fPIC
LDFLAGS = -L../../src/common -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mit-krb5 -Wl,--as-needed
LDFLAGS_EX =
LDFLAGS_SL =
LIBS = -lpgcommon -lpgport -lpthread -lselinux -lxslt -lxml2 -lpam -lssl -lcrypto -lgssapi_krb5 -lz -ledit -lrt -lcrypt -ldl -lm
VERSION = PostgreSQL 10.0
```

Which in turn doesn't make any sense at all. We just want a legacy version of 9.5 installed to avoid going down a rabbit hole of various package upgrades. What am I missing?

Comment: What "necessary" repo did you add?  You seem to have pulled in a postgresql 10.  Check the /usr/lib/postgresql directory for all installed versions. 9.5.9 is the version on my 16.04 system.

Comment: `deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main 9.5`

Comment: Listing the contents of `/usr/lib/postgresql` indicates 9.5 as well, so I'm confused why pg_config reports otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

It ended up being another dependency getting installed (libpq-dev) without a specified version, so it would install the latest (10), which included its own version of `pg_config`, which would then in turn cause downstream packages that were dependent on getting the version from it to break.

Comment: James, what specifically did you do? After you erased the libpq-dev, what version did you installed after?

Comment: @user3867776 we simply installed libpq-dev with a specified version that more closely matched the version of Postgres we had installed. Problem solved.

Comment: my libpq-dev also was for the postgres 10 version, but the pg_config first looks at the postgres-server-dev-XY package that's installed...I just installed and django stopped complaining...

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL version to remove: **10** 
PostgreSQL version to install: **9.5**

#### 1. Stop PostgreSQL cluster:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql stop
```

#### 2. Completely remove postgreSQL:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge postgr*
$ sudo apt-get autoremove

# check /usr/share/postgresql/ directory and remove '10' subdirectory if needed:
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/share/postgresql/10
```

#### 3. Install packages:

```
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.5 postgresql-9.5 postgresql-client-9.5 postgresql-contrib-9.5 libpq-dev
$ psql --version
...
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.5.*
```

#### (3.1.) change the configuration (if required):

```
$ sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf
...
```

#### 4. Start PostgreSQL cluster:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start
...
[ ok ] Starting postgresql (via systemctl): postgresql.service.
```

#### 5. Check installed version:

```
pg_config
```